# How we can change the font in this field of MS Access?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-office

Actually I want to change the font of this field in forms of ms access , is there any way for that? for example Tahoma instead of Calibri

[image]

I change that from form property but it won't change why?

and this is my form in design view :
[image]

MS Access 2007 , 2010 , 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The why?**

- The reason why your change isn't applied is because you are using the form in Datasheet view instead of form view

**How do you change the font on a datasheet?**

- Run the form
- Click inside any row inside datasheet view then Change font under `Home Tab`
- Basically you work with the `First screenshot` you posted, any change in font in `Screenshot 2` view doesn't affect the output

Comment: You shouldn't change every time, the change will stay!

Answer (score 0):

In your table, and forms it's at the top in the home tab.
[image]

changing in the table and controls of your form works the same way.

[image]